# The Difference Inner Join Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm just curious, if i have table a and table b.

I write query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM table a INNER JOIN table b ON table a.id = table b.id
```

I write query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM table b INNER JOIN table a ON table b.id = table a. id
```

What is the difference both of above query?

Thank you

Comment: There is no difference,in the results at least.

Comment: heheh...exactly thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second table matches data with the first one.
So it is better to put smaller table on the second place.

Comment: not necessarily since there is no where... it is still pulling all records from both tables where the join matches... and if criteria, I would ensure index and query from the larger table listed first.

Comment: For major DBSM there's no difference, the engine ill choose the order to do nested loop based on internal statistics. For MS SQL I'm sure it ill work at least with seven (the mileage can vary) joins.

Comment: Yes optimizer would decide in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

When using `INNER JOIN` , there is no difference in resultset returned except  in order of columns when `SELECT *` is used i.e. columns are not explicitly mentioned.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table a 
     INNER JOIN table b 
        ON table a.id = table b.id
```

returns columns from **tableA** followed by columns from **tableB**

```
SELECT * 
FROM table b 
     INNER JOIN table a 
             ON table b.id = table a. id
```

returns columns from **tableB** followed by columns from **tableA**

Comment: This is correct. Furthermore, on SQL Server, both queries will perform equally well, no matter the size of each table, thanks to the query optimizer.

Comment: I think there is a general knowledge of sql server in stack overflow's users.